# Tabulator: Column headers lag behind in horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, typescript, tabulator

I have a large (some ~30 columns, 10k+ rows) data set I am displaying in a Tabulator table. The table has 100% height set and vertical scroll runs very smooth with the virtual DOM. But when I scroll horizontally (my columns span some 3-4 times the screen width on my resolution, and this is intended), the scrolling is again very smooth but the column headers (including their filter boxes) do not follow the scroll immediately, instead they sort of lag behind. When the scroll motion stops, the headers "catch up" in a second or so.

I guess this is because the table component supports sticky ("frozen") columns and therefore their position gets adjusted on-the-fly based on scroll events from the table content, but since I am not using such columns, I was wondering if the laggy / jerky movement of the headers can be disabled and have the headers directly scroll along with the table rows?

Comment: Displaying 10k+ rows at a time, I would also expect lags in the best case scenario, crashes and unresponsiveness in the worse. You are getting your browser and your machine to its knees, and I'm not certain anybody will read or need all of these at once on their screen. Do you really need that many rows concurrently on screen? Can't you implement pagination or something?

Comment: @JeremyThille probably so yes. Will see how well the virtual DOM handles the production data armounts. But that aside, the said horizontal scroll issue occurs rather heavily in my testing environment with just 200 rows and is not related to browser performance per se, as they clearly are detached from the table content's scroll pane.